# RNGscope segmentation fault

Tags: inline, rcpp

I've been coding some simulations using inline/RcppArmadillo and stumbled upon a problem with RNGScope. Is this a bug or am I doing something really dumb?? I've emptied the function out to make it readable (see below).

Cheers,
Ed

```
library(inline)
code_cpp <- '
using namespace arma;
// From R  
uvec               x0 = as<uvec>(x0_r);
vec          time_vec = as<vec>(time_vec_r);
// Declare variables
umat        simulation_data=zeros<umat>(x0.n_elem, time_vec.n_elem);
RNGScope scope;
return wrap(simulation_data);
'

gillespie_sim <- cxxfunction(body = code_cpp, 
                              sig = signature(x0_r = "integer", time_vec_r= "numeric"), 
                        plugin = "RcppArmadillo") 


x0    <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
time_vec <- 1:800
set.seed(23) 
for(i in 1:100000) out2  <- gillespie_sim(x0_r=x0,time_vec_r=time_vec)
```

The error I get

R(43305) malloc: *** error for object 0x108c30a00: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably     modified after being freed.
   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
   Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I see two issues:

a) You use `umat`, but we have no `unsigned int` in R, so this will get lots of very inefficient copies.  I changed it to `mat`, but `imat` should work too.

b) You loop *a lot* with `for(i in 1:100000)`.  We have seen similar issue with "gazillions" of object creations.  We are not sure where the bug is.

With a smaller N it does not seem to happen (as often).  We'll take a look and see if `RNGScope` has anything to do with it -- but that is a very simple object.

Thanks for the bug report.  Consider using `rcpp-devel` next time, please.

*Edit:* Also note that when using `Rcpp` vectors, the error does not seem to manifest itself.  So you could use the two-step method of first initializing Rcpp objects and then initializing Armadillo objects from it -- the `fastLm.r` file in the package has an example of that.

```
suppressMessages(library(Rcpp))
suppressMessages(library(inline))

useRcpp <- function() {
    code_cpp <- '
// From R
NumericVector  x0(x0_r);
NumericVector  time_vec(time_vec_r);
// Declare variables
NumericMatrix  simulation_data(x0.size(), time_vec.size());
RNGScope scope;
return simulation_data;
'

cxxfunction(body = code_cpp,
            sig = signature(x0_r = "integer", time_vec_r= "numeric"),
            plugin = "Rcpp")
}

gillespie_sim <- useRcpp()

x0    <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
time_vec <- 1:800
set.seed(23)
for(i in 1:100000) out2  <- gillespie_sim(x0_r=x0,time_vec_r=time_vec)
cat("Done\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Not sure if it helps, but if I comment RNGScope and add in the GetRNGstate();PutRNGstate(); I no longer get the error. I've taken note of rcpp-devel. Thanks, Ed

Comment: That's a good follow-up. But do look at our RNGScope class -- it is about as simple as they come.  Why would that go haywire?

Comment: Yes, it's just a clever way of simplifying the RNGstate stuff. It should give no problem. Unfortunately my knowledge of c++ is paper thin, so I have no idea why it might screw anything up. On another note, for some reason if I swap the return wrap(simulation_data); for returning an integer return wrap(22); it also stops crashing. Ed

Comment: Yes it quite clearly is an interaction. We've been after this for a while but it is a hard bug to squash.

Comment: Incidentally, Dirk did manage to squash this on a related issue.  http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2013-May/005838.html